# How to solve this differential equation? $u'=\frac{u^a}{u^b+u^c}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$. The differential equation is $$y'+1=\frac{(x+y)^a}{(x+y)^b+(x+y)^c}.$$

With the change of variable $u=y+x$ it is not difficult to see that the equation is equivalent to $$u'=\frac{u^a}{u^b+u^c}$$ which is in turn equivalent to $$(u^{b-a}+u^{c-a})u'=1$$ so integrating both sides we have $$\int u^{b-a}du + \int u^{c-a}du=x+c$$ and we can then consider when $b-a=-1$, when $c-a=-1$, when both $c-a=b-a=-1$ and when both are different to $-1$, but in some cases I believe it is not possible to obtain a simple expression of $u$ in terms of $x$.

How should one proceed?

Comment: Usually the solution to exact differential equations like this are left in the implicit form of $f(x,y)=0$ if an explicit formula cannot be found or if a formula is complex enough to obscure some needed symmetry/pattern.